# Why Redis performance is slow?

Tags: php, redis, phpredis

I have a PHP app with 200 req/sec with a session table on MySQL with `lastactivity`, so I have to update it  on every request. This keeps our MySQL server really busy so I decided to use REDIS to store these sessions.

After implementing REDIS on the project our response time increased from 500ms to 3-5s.
Our REDIS server has 15k-20k keys `no persistence` and I'm using `SET` with expire time to store keys and `GET` for retrieve them.

For search an specific key I've used `SCAN`. I've tested different limits 100,500,1000 and 10,000 on SCAN.

Our keys schema : `sessions:40:0:DZOJUxMWVnuIMcf4ef0307a832efc46771afde81292b174e91c94d08E23YK3YoMU`

REDIS INFO :

```
redis_version: 6.0.6
connected_clients: 200 to 500
instantaneous_ops_per_sec: 4,000 to 10,000
```

Is there any thing that I can do to improve response time ?

Comment: It seems your Redis server is good(5k-10k ops per sec, generally a good Redis server can serve for 100k ops/sec, depends on hardware). Can you check the network latency from your client to Redis server?

Comment: well, since it's on Kubernetes infrastructure, we don't have any network latency here.